# Getting driver cannot be resolved or not a field error on Selenium script

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

We have a Selenium script to open a Chrome browser, but in the below line of code we are getting following error

> messsage-driver cannot be resolved or is not a field.

```
WebDriver.driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver.driver=new ChromeDriver();
change it to:
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

I think you got simple syntax error. In order to help you further code below is a setup for chrome driver in java.

```
System.setProperty("PATH\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.navigate().to(URL);  
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator)).sendKeys();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

I used the above code successfully to solve the same problem.